# Can't build Maven project after being copied on another computer

Tags: java, spring, maven, netbeans, pom.xml

I'm getting "The goal you specified requires a project to execute but there is no POM in this directory (C:\Windows)" after trying to build my Maven project. On my computer it works fine but I can't build it on a second computer (there should be all resources the project needs).

Thanks for answers.

Comment: Is there a pom file in the directory you are executing the mvn command in?

Comment: Yes, I have my pom.xml in Project Files

Comment: The message says you are executing the mvn command in C:\Windows. are you sure you are in the right directory? doesn't look like it.

Comment: Now I see on the top of the console ""CMD.EXE was started with the above path as the current directory. UNC paths are not supported. Defaulting to Window directory." that's probably causing the problem, or isn't?

Comment: Is your project located on a network drive?

Comment: Yes, it's a network drive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your project appears to be located on a network drive, so cmd is defaulting back to your windows directory. You should move your project to a local directory.

Comment: It's a university computer, so I don't have rights to do that, is there any other possibility?

Comment: Can you put it on a flash drive? Windows doesn't appear to support building maven projects on a network drive.

Comment: Probably can try it but not now because I'm on the university PC via RDP, thank you very much for your time.